# How do I interpret this notation?

Tags: functions

While studying functions I came across an exercise which looks more or less like this:

Let $f:\left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}\rightarrow \left\{0,1,2,6,12\right\}$ be a function defined by $f\left(x\right)=x^2-x$. Is the function invertible? What's its domain and its range?

Now, I know what are the range and the domain, and what means to a function being invertible. I just don't know what the first notation refers to and how do I relate it to the traditional notation for a function ($f\left(x\right)=x^2-x$). Could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a somewhat more familiar example, a function $g$ defined as
\begin{align*}
&g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\tag{1}\\
&g(x)=x^2-x
\end{align*}
We have in (1) a function $g$ defined with domain $\mathbb{R}$ which is also the codomain and the values of $g$ specified by the rule $g(x)=x^2-x$.

> In OPs example we have in fact the same situation, namely a function $f$ with domain $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and codomain $\{0,1,2,6,12\}$ which can be written as in (1) as
>   \begin{align*}
> &f:\{0,1,2,3,4\}\to\{0,1,2,6,12\}\\
> &f(x)=x^2-x
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

It refers to a function $f$, the $\rightarrow$ represents the *mapping* or better to say correspondence from the **domain** set (the $\{...\}$ at left) to the **codomain** set (the right $\{...\}$).